# Error: Field "is_admin" does not exist in model "res.users"

Tags: odoo

When I go to Settings and click on users& companies to create users or groups I get this error:

```
Error while validating view near:

<field name="employee_ids" invisible="1"/>
<field name="employee_id" invisible="1"/>
<button string="Create employee" type="object" name="action_create_employee" attrs="{'invisible': ['|', '|', ('id', '=', False), ('share', '=', True), ('employee_id', '!=', False)]}"/>
<!-- share is not correctly recomputed because it depends on fields of reified view => invisible before saving (id=False) -->
</header>

Field "is_admin" does not exist in model "res.users"
```

Bear in mind that I did not add any custom coding I just built an app using Odoo studio I only added custom coding for computed fields such as:

```
for record in self:
    record['x_vaccancies'] = len(record['x_studio_one2many_field_t0PSY'])
   
for shop in record.x_studio_one2many_field_t0PSY:
    if shop.x_studio_selection_field_I8q1t == "rented":
        record['x_vaccancies'] -= 1
```

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Can you add which Odoo version you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try update base module. Maybe this one could help you.
2. Do you have more than 1 db on this stage? It looks like in the other db you install custom module with this field "is_admin" in model "res.users", that not installed in current db.